# How do you submit on enter key press in a Chakra-UI input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm creating a component that contains an input that directs the user to a new tab upon pressing enter or clicking the search button. The search button functions correctly, however I'm having trouble getting the input to call the handleSubmit method on enter key press. As of now, pressing the enter key does nothing. How can I achieve this?
code:

```
  const LinkCard = (props) => {
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org");
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org");
  };

  return (
    <Flex borderWidth="1px" borderRadius="lg" alignItems="center">
      {props.icon}
      <Box>{props.websiteName}</Box>
      <InputGroup>
        <Input
          placeholder={"Search " + props.websiteName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          flexGrow="1"
          m="2%"
        />
        <Link href={props.url} passHref={true}>
          <a>
            <InputRightElement m="2%">
              <Button onClick={handleClick}>
                <FaSearch />
              </Button>
            </InputRightElement>
          </a>
        </Link>
      </InputGroup>
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
return (
<form
  onSubmit={e=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.assign('?wd=' + value)
  }}>
  <input value={value} onChange={(e)=> setValue(e.currentTarget.value)} />
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
)
```

or

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

return (
<>
  <input 
     value={value} 
     onChange={(e)=> setValue(e.currentTarget.value)} 
     onKeyPress={e=> {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
           location.assign('?wd=' + value)
        }
     }}
  />
  <button onClick={()=> location.assign('?wd=' + value)}>Search</button>
</>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**There are 2 possible ways you can achieve that:**

- Add a key listener on your `submitHandler`:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org");
  }
};
```

- Having a `form` around your input and add submit an event:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <Input
    placeholder={"Search " + props.websiteName}
    onChange={handleChange}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    flexGrow="1"
    m="2%"
  />
</form>;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Typescript Answer**

I found this was a common enough problem to create a few util helper functions for:

```
import {KeyboardEvent} from "react"

export function handleEnterKeyPress<T = Element>(f: () => void){
    return handleKeyPress<T>(f, "Enter")
}

function handleKeyPress<T = Element>(f: () => void, key: string){
    return (e: KeyboardEvent<T>) => {
        if(e.key === key){
            f()
        }
    }
}
```

The functions are "higher order" in the sense that they lift a regular, zero argument void function up and give you back a nicely typed event handler that can be passed straight into the `onKeyDown` method.

Sample code:

```
<Input {...props} onKeyDown={handleEnterKeyPress(myFunction)}/>
```

Where `myFunction` is any void function you'd like to run whenever the enter key is pressed.

Note: You should use `onKeyDown` rather than `onKeyPress` as the latter [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event).

#### Update

If you want to handle multiple keys, I've found a slightly more flexible version of the above to be helpful:

```
import {KeyboardEvent} from "react"

export function handleEnterKeyPress<T = Element>(f: () => void){
    return handleKeyPress<T>({Enter: f})
}

export type KeyPressMap = {
    [key: string]: () => void
}

export function handleKeyPress<T = Element>(map: KeyPressMap){
    return (e: KeyboardEvent<T>) => {        
        const handler = map[e.key]
        if(handler !== undefined){
            handler()
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your component, you can call it with something like this for example, where `handleEnter` and `handleEscape` are assumed to be some functions accessible to your component:

```
const keyPressHandlers = {
    Enter: handleEnter,
    Escape: handleEscape
}

return <Input onKeyDown={handleKeyPress(keyPressHandlers)}/>
```